# Silverlight database using XML

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq

I am working on porting an old application to Silverlight (version 5). The application has many forms with combo boxes who's items are conditionally populated. This is being handled in the old application through an Access database stored within the application and queried using the DAO object library. I was thinking Silverlight would let me mimic this functionality, but I found out that Silverlight does not allow for local database storage and manipulation (please correct me if I am wrong). I cannot go the web service route for database manipulation because this app has to work offline and Out of Browser on Mac and Windows.

So, I am looking for alternatives. It seems that I can use XML and LINQ to achieve a sort of quasi-database. My question regarding this is will it still work on Mac and Windows platforms? Any other alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: Silverlight + has to work offline.  I think you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Have you looked at IsolatedStorage? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)

Comment: @cadrell0 Silverlight provides Out of Browser and offline functionality AND it works cross platform. What's your suggestion?

Comment: @Brad are you suggesting using IsolatedStorage for the XML files? If I am understanding it right, its used to protect files stored with an application?

Comment: @Ethan I don't have all of your project requirements, so I can't make a suggestion.  And please don't take my comment as a knock on Silverlight.  I am the primary Silverlight developer at my company and I really like it.  I'm just not convinced you should be using it here.

Comment: @cadrell0 sorry if my reply sounded a little coarse. I did even use all caps there haha :) My remark was based on your impression that Silverlight was not a possible offline solution. This application primarily does a bunch of calculations. All of the calculation logic has no dependencies on uncommon or third-party libraries. We want to make it available for both Mac and Windows users. Going with Silverlight also gave us the added bonus of being able to run it in browser and always having the most up to date version there (not to mention the simple updating for OOB).

Comment: Have you looked at http://sterling.codeplex.com/. Sterling is a lightweight NoSQL object-oriented database for .Net 4.0, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7 that works with your existing class structures. Sterling supports full LINQ to Object queries over keys and indexes for fast retrieval of information from large data sets.

Comment: @Rus Yes, I have been looking into Sterling. We were hoping to stay away from third-party dependencies due to some bad luck in the past. It's definitely a possibility if it comes down to it though. I think I'm just going to take a shot at using XML and see how it all falls. Thanks to all for the suggestions and discussion.

Comment: @Ethan I was thinking maybe even be able to create an access db because I know you can use a SQL CE DB and use LINQ TO SQL to query it.

Comment: @Brad Everything I'm reading seems to say that it requires COM which would only work in Windows. I'm really needing this to be cross platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the suggestions given. I'm going with Brad's suggestion in the comments on the question and using IsolatedStorage. While I wish I could just use COM and MS SQL CE, I need cross-platform. I also wish I could just use a third-party solution, but we are trying to not have dependencies on third party software and stay away from extra costs too.

Linq to XML is proving to be very useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use siaqodb (http://siaqodb.com/) this one is commercial. Another option http://sterling.codeplex.com/

this will be stored in your isolated storage, but if you want to keep it in the users hard disks, you could ouse OOB Trusted application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have looked into these two, but we are wanting to stay away from third-party tools.